# How to get index of a character in spanned object?

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, spanned, spannablestringbuilder

i have this string `String thestring="<p>Abcd® X (CSX) Open Cell</p>"`, 
I have used Html.from to skip the tags from printing like this:

```
Spanned spst = Html.fromHtml(thestring);
```

I also want the ® to be superscript, so i have used the following code,

```
SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder(spst);
        cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(),thestring.indexOf("®") ,thestring.indexOf("®")+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), thestring.indexOf("®"),thestring.indexOf("®")+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        content.setText(cs, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

But this is not making the ® superscript, the index is different for spanned object and the string, how can i get the index of ® in the spanned string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert `Spanned` to `String`, this will give you "clean", stripped from HTML string

```
String strippedFromHTMLString = spst.toString();
```

and then in `setSpan` use it instead of original `thestring`

```
int indexOfR = strippedFromHTMLString.indexOf("®");
SpannableStringBuilder cs = new SpannableStringBuilder(spst);
cs.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(),  indexOfR, indexOfR+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
cs.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f),  indexOfR, indexOfR+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
content.setText(cs, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```